# How to access set of pincodes within 5km range with the input of one pincode

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, google-api

> When the user enters pincode then I want to show the list of pin codes
>   within **5km-10km** range of that Pincode.

Suppose the user enters PinCode:400068 then I want a list of Pincodes within **5km** range of 400068 Pincode.

Comment: What has the number 400068 got to do with a location (please clarify in the question rather than assuming people know what you are talking about)

Comment: Please show people what you have tried so far and did not work, possibly with some code example, so that they can better understand your question and try to help